# Как через метод POST добавлять в конец массива

Tags: php

есть код. Когда приходит пост запрос то он просто меняет нулевой элемент в массиве, то есть так :`Array ( [0] => gosha )` А нужно что бы он записывал каждый пост метод в конец и складывал их. то есть `Array ( [0] => gosha ,[1] => gosha )`

```
$test = array();


$testp = $_POST['test'];

array_push($test, $testp);
$_SERVER['test'] = $test;


print_r($_SERVER['test']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала внимательно перечитайте документацию.
[array_push](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-push.php)

Для добавления элемента в конец массива достаточно:

```
<?php
    $arr = []; // $arr = array(); // PHP 5.3 style
    $arr[] = "one";
    $arr[] = "two";
    $arr[] = "three";
    $arr[] = "four";

    var_dump($arr); // Array( [0] => "one", [0] => "two", [0] => "three", [0] => "four")
```

В вашем случае:

```
<?php

    $test = array(); // $test = []; // PHP 5.4+ style
    $test[] = $_POST['test'];
```

Для информации **НИКОГДА** не меняйте системные массивы типа `$_SERVER/$_POST...`

Comment: Так не совсем понял как это работает... Продукты будут браться с POST и неизвестно сколько их будет

Comment: @Gaioz А можно пример того как они храняться приходят в `$_POST`?